# How to access URL parameters in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, spree, rails-routing

I'm experiencing a problem with my Spree routing.

Requests are being sent to `/spreeapi`, when they should be sent to `/api`

Some of the requests have URL parameters like so:

```
/spreeapi/option_types?q%5Bname_cont%5D=&_=1407867241807
```

I have attempted to add this routing:

```
mount Spree::Core::Engine, :at => '/shop'
get "/spreeapi(/*path)" => redirect{ |params| "/shop/api/#{params[:path]}".chomp("/") }
```

While this connects the request to the correct path, **I am losing all the URL params**.

How can I rewrite my route redirect to include them.

Answer (score 2):

This was my final solution (thanks for help though @Balrick):

```
get "/spreeapi(/*path)" => redirect{ |params, request| "/shop/api/#{params.delete(:path)}?#{request.params.to_query}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following line that append the query string to the redirected urls

```
get "/spreeapi(/*path)" => redirect{ |params| "/shop/api/#{params.delete(:path)}?#{params.to_query}" }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get Started GET "/spreeapi/taxons?per_page=50&page=1&without_children=true&q%5Bname_cont%5D=&_=1407944032930" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-13 10:33:58 -0500


Started GET "/shop/api/taxons" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-13 10:33:58 -0500
Processing by Spree::Api::TaxonsController#index as JSON